# Create a list of dates and insert in URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm still relatively new to Python so bear with me but here's my question. I have a specific list of dates that need to be inserted into a URL and then loop through each URL to scrape the web data. I've done similar tasks but in instances where I don't need to create a list. An example of that is below.

```
url_template = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/play-
index/lineup_finder.cgi?request=1&match=single&player_id=&offset={set}"

lineup_df = pd.DataFrame()

for set in range(0, 12600, 100):  # for each page
    url = url_template.format(set=set)  # get the url

page_request = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_request.text,"lxml")

column_headers = [th.getText() for th in 
        soup.findAll('tr', limit=2)[1].findAll('th')]

# get lineup data
data_rows = soup.findAll('tr')[2:] 
lineup_data = [[td.getText() for td in data_rows[i].findAll(['td','th'])]
        for i in range(len(data_rows))]

# Turn page data into a DataFrame
page_df = pd.DataFrame(lineup_data, columns=column_headers)

# Append to the big dataframe
lineup_df = lineup_df.append(page_df, ignore_index=True)
```

So basically what I'm looking to accomplish is replacing for set in range with a list of dates. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: So what is the problem of your code?

Comment: I posted that code as an example of what I'm looking to accomplish except "range(0, 12600, 100)" needs to be replaced with a list of roughly 100 dates from 2017 to 2018.

Answer (score 1):

Your code run through the process of creating an url but it does not capture it in a list as you want, a list comprehension will do the job. Then you can run through the url_list for each url created.off

```
url_template = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/playindex/lineup_finder.cgi?request=1&match=single&player_id=&offset={offset}"
url_list=[url_template.format(offset=offset) for offset in range(0, 12600, 100)]
for url in url_list:
    # the rest of code here
```

Comment: Thanks, that puts me a step in the right direction.